# Can't create or update product

Tags: magento

Magento leaves off update existing products.
Logs are empty. I made successfully reindex and recache.

When I press button SAVE the script runs close to 5 minutes and ends by 500 error.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFO:

at query log I found next query:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`
```

Can this affect modifying troubles?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the maximum_execution_time of php ist set to low, to fullfil your task. It seems that magento is trying to reindex your prices and fails to that.

The 500 error means server error, what could be anything on server side. But in most situations it's an PHP Fatal Error, that should be written to some webserver log files, if you have them enabled. Please check your server logs.